# How to power 30 LED 9W downlight?

Tags: led

I bought a cheap LED downlight from ebay. The LED driver (spelt DRINER) that came with it, I do not trust - it is probably dangerous.
It states that its output is DC12-24V, 300mA. (which does not add up to 9W, if I'm not mistaken). When I tested it, its voltage was around 14V with the downlight connected.

The LED strip insight the downlight consists of 30 LEDs with the following print on it:
RF120-XX-289X7-2835-30LED

[image: Picture of the downlight]

1. If the 30 LEDs were connected in series, wouldn't that bring the supply voltage up to around 90V (white LEDs with a drop of around 3V? each)
2. How could I test if they did something like 5 LEDs in series each and the 6 groups are than connected parallel?
3. Could I use a "wall-wart" power supply with let's say 24V and use a constant current DC-DC LM2596 Step-down Adjustable Power Supply Module CC-CV LED Driver (as they are available on eBay)?

This should at least reduce the chance of "live" AC voltage leaking to the LEDs. It would most likely not change the fire risk if the step-down converter is faulty/badly designed - what do you think?

Comment: Assumptions from your text: There are 5 or 6 branches of LED's, each 6 or 5 pcs. 14V / 5 = 2.8V which sounds reasonable for white LED's. The power supply is likely a continuous current supply. Whatever load you attach, it will source 300mA and it will change the output voltage accordingly within limits (12 ~ 24V). Power is more like 14V × 300 mA = 4.2W, about half the expected power.

Comment: Note that for anything that does not have a good datasheets statements like "X W" are almost always marketing nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it was said the 30 are not on series but they are tied at smaller groups at parallel and so on series.

I've already did a job where I designed a headlight with bright adjustment. I used a LM317 to do the job, and here you get a calculator for its output (explicit on DS) http://www.electronics-lab.com/articles/LM317/LM317.gif. Instead of the potentiometer, I used another resistor as a switch.